How to change textview that is not on my screen
I am trying to load data from the cloud and then display it in a text view. This means that after the user logs in, before they decide to change to any of the other 3 screens in the app, I want to populate the textviews with the proper information. The only problem is that the view ids that are trying to be accessed are null since those fragments haven't been loaded. When I try the same process using the view id of a on screen textview it works but on the other fragments no dice.
I tried this in my code
public void updateFragData(FragmentData fragData, Fragment frag)
    {
        if(fragData != null)
        {
            Log.d("uFrag", "" + R.id.Class1);
            //String[] text = (String[]) fragData.getText().toArray();
            Integer[] id = fragData.getId().toArray(new Integer[fragData.getId().size()]);
            Integer[] visibility = fragData.getVisibility().toArray(new Integer[fragData.getVisibility().size()]);
            for(int x = 0; x < visibility.length; x++)
            {
                Log.d("update123", "" + id[x]);
                EditText temp = (EditText) findViewById(id[x]);
                //temp.setText(text[x]);
                temp.setVisibility(visibility[x]);
            }
        }
    }

and even though "id[x]" is confirmed to be the right id, it returns null since the textview is offscreen so I was wondering if anyone knew a way to either load this data wihtout changing what is displayed to the user or work around this somehow

Maybe you can pass the data as arguments to the fragments. O use the same ViewModel instance in both fragments, tied to the activity lifecycle.
Check this doc for more details:  https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate
